# Does Class template argument deduction works with std::map?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I tried to get CTAD to work with `std::map`, but I can not get it to work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::string_literals;

int main() {
    std::vector v{1,2,3}; // ok
    std::map m{{4, "four"s},{7,"seven"s},{1,"one"s},{5,"five"s}}; // error
}
```

Is there a way to make it work, or is `std::map` to complicated for it to work?

Comment: The commented line compiles for me once I change the first pair to `std::pair{4, "four"s}`, so it's not all bad.

Comment: The problem is initializer lists don't have a type so it really tough to try and deduce one.  For the most part CTAD isn't going to work with nested lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that this `std::map m{{4, "four"s},{7,"seven"s},{1,"one"s},{5,"five"s}}; // error` is an `{}` of `{}`s, and CTAD doesn't do that.

If you do `std::map m{std::pair{4, "four"s},{7,"seven"s},{1,"one"s},{5,"five"s}};` it becomes an initializer list, which CTAD works on.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But can't, won't or shouldn't the compiler see that the inner init-lists are pair-initializers? I would think that a deduction guide to that could be created, maybe?

Comment: @towi Like I said, CTAD doesn't do that.  "Could" doesn't matter; if you want to know why CTAD doesn't do that, you can ask a new question and hope someone who attended standards meetings on the topic weighs in.